# Is there any way to create proxy profiles in windows?

Tags: windows-8, proxy

I have to change my proxy settings frequently because I get internet connection in different places like university, office, library and home. Whenever I get internet connection from one of those places, I always have to change the proxy settings in my pc. I don't remember the proxy IPs at all. So, what I'm doing is, copying the relevant proxy IP from a text file and changing the settings. 
This been a real pain for me. Is there any way I can manage these proxies like profiles? (like in Mac) Or are there any software to get done this job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the system proxy from the command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/709096/how-can-i-change-the-system-proxy-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Another [In Windows 7, how to change proxy settings from command line?](http://superuser.com/q/419696)

Comment: The question is not having exact match as the poster asks for the possibility of saving proxy settings as profiles which can be easily managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registry script:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819961
- https://www.serverfault.com/questions/17976/how-to-switch-proxy-settings-via-script

Profile based tools:

- http://www.proxyswitcher.net/
- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Switch-IE-Proxy-b525ae0d

Please perform a good research before posting.... :)

Comment: I will! I think I need to have workarounds on methods you have suggested.

Comment: The proxy settings applied to IE is also effective system wide. Exceptions are software like  Firefox which maintains its own proxy settings.